# Could not load file or assembly at server

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, sql-server

My project is working in my system as well as other system but when I deployed at
server its not working.following error is come:-could not load file or assembly pechkin or one of its dependencies,an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.Please help me.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its was working, when i set enable32bitapplication=true in IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Copy Local property of reference dll's to True, this may help

Comment: How i can set Copy Local property of reference dll's to True? please tell me procedure.

Comment: Open solution in Visual Studio , click references,right click reference(.dll) you want and click properties, in the opened window you will see

Answer (score -2):

Check the configuration file and the assembly versions which are referenced for the project.

Comment: assembly versions is 32-bit but my system have win-7 64 bit till its working in my system .in server its not working